# Trigger event when headerCheckboxSelection is marked?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I've been reading the `ag-grid` documentation and I haven't been able to find out if there's any event to know when the checkbox to select or un-select all column was clicked.

I know I can use `onRowSelected()` but I need to know when *Select* or *un-Select All* is clicked so I can make a different operation.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see an option as of right now either, what I would do though is listen for the `onRowSelected` then compare the selection range (using `gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows`) to the total rows (using `gridOptions.api.getModel`) and do something if they are the same

Alternatively you could try adding a listener to the select all element it can be found with the class `.ag-header-select-all` though I am not quite sure how I would do that.

Comment: I'm gonna do it this way for now. Thanks!